# Overuse of Pragma Pack(1)

Tags: c++, c, gnu

What causes padding due to overuse of `#pragma pack(1)`? What actually happens in backstage?

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        uint8_t SAM;
        #pragma pack(1)
        struct {
                uint8_t sm:1;  
                uint8_t sm1:3 ;
                uint8_t sm2 :1 ; 
                uint8_t sm3 :1 ; 
                uint8_t sm4 :1 ;
                uint8_t sm5:1 ; 
            };
          #pragma pack()
        };
}SAM1;
#pragma pack()
```

Comment: `#pragma pack()` is something from microsoft. Prefer `__attribute__((__packed__))` in gnu. `What causes padding due to overuse of pragma Pack(1)?` What does it mean? What does it mean to "overuse of pragma pack(1)"? How do you observe the padding? Please post an [MCVE]. Are you compiling the code as C or as C++? Which compiler are you using? What compielr options? What compiler version? `What actually happens in backstage?` is a very broad question. Where exactly is "backstage"? Is there a "stage"? Note, that you do `#pragma pack()` _before_ SAM1.

Comment: `#pragma pack(1)` has no effect on bit fields. It works only for byte-level packing. Just read the documentation.

Comment: @KamilCuk overuse means if i am not using #pragma pack inside SAM1 struct then it's work fine but when i am using pragma pack inside then i am getting padding. I am compiling the code as C. and backstage means how it will work with memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your annotated code:

```
#pragma pack(1)
// from here on the compiler will align fields on 1 byte
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        uint8_t SAM;
        #pragma pack(1)
        // there is no use for this pragma on a bit field
        // packing was already at 1 byte
        struct {
                uint8_t sm:1;  
                uint8_t sm1:3 ;
                uint8_t sm2 :1 ; 
                uint8_t sm3 :1 ; 
                uint8_t sm4 :1 ;
                uint8_t sm5:1 ; 
            };
          #pragma pack()
          // from the next struct or union declaration the compiler will use default packing
        };
}SAM1;
#pragma pack()
// from here on the compiler uses default packing
```

"Pack takes effect at the first struct, union, or class declaration after the pragma is seen."

Comment: @NileshSolanki Note that the second `#pragma pack()` is meaningless anyway, as you set to default already previously. There's no relation between different pragmas, only the latestly set value applies. You can combine with push/pop, though, then you can create such relation, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=vs-2019.

Comment: Thank you @Aconcagua.that's  also useful comment.